# Can I as a Bloodhunter create mutagens without doing a short or long rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, blood-hunter

As a 2020 version of the [Bloodhunter/mutagen order](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/blood-hunter), at lvl 3 I can create one mutagens in a short/long rest.

I read this [handbook](https://rpgbot.net/dnd5/characters/classes/matt-mercers-blood-hunter/2020.html):

> As a possible fix: Instead of preparing your mutagens during a rest, you prepare reagents for mutagens.

> Creating a mutagen requires one minute of uninterrupted work with these reagents and a set of alchemist's tools. This allows the Blood Hunter a bit more flexibility with their mutagens, but not so much that they can change them during combat."

I don´t really understand where he gets that with the reagents. I can´t find it in the books and nothing about it on the internet.

This way I could do a 1 min pause and prepare the mutagen without doing a short rest.

I hope you can help me to understand it better.

Comment: @NautArch https://rpgbot.net/dnd5/characters/classes/matt-mercers-blood-hunter/2020.html

And I use the Bloodhunter from the DnDbeyond site from critical role.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question... it sounds like the quote you've posted is proposing a change to the RAW version of the Bloodhunter in order to make Mutagens more flexible. Are you asking if that change is balanced, or are you asking what the rules-as-written say?

Answer (score 6):

Based on reading the guide you linked to, the author of the guide is proposing a house-rule to try to fix something he perceives as a problem with the Bloodhunter's Order of the Mutant subclass. To me, it seems like the guy who wrote the guide is rather missing the point, though.

> ...there's little incentive to prepare [most mutagens] unless you can find out what you're facing well ahead of time.

Well, yeah, that's the whole concept of the subclass. The Order of the Mutant is largely based on *The Witcher* -- and one of the main mechanics of the Witcher games (and of how Geralt operates in the novels) is that he has to do the footwork to understand what he's facing and prepare for the fight before he goes in, waiting patiently and engaging only on his own terms. If he gets jumped or tries to skip the prep time, he's going into the battle severely weakened.

To me that analysis sounds a lot like "It sucks that wizards have to prep their spells in the morning, so here's a house rule that lets them just decide what spells they want later."  Sure, that powers-up the class, but it ruins the flavor of the thing.

Also, to be honest, I don't actually see much of a difference between spending a minute or an hour to prepare mutagens, as far as the gameplay goes. It's very rare that you have ten turns to spare getting ready and can't spend an hour instead; usually you're either immediately in combat and just have to deal, or you have the opportunity to withdraw and take some time to prepare first, which can be a few rounds or a whole short rest.

Comment: Just on supporting our statements; I would assume there's plenty of statements from Mercer on design notes and inspirations, but it would be very good to link to one regarding the Witcher aspect.

Comment: I can find a statement that "game designer Anthony Joyce... cites Andrzej Sapkowski's *The Witcher* as inspiration" and "Matt Mercer has cited that his blood hunter class was inspired by *The Witcher* series", but I don't know where the citations happened; I would imagine either in an introduction to a book or in a podcast somewhere. Honestly the connection is pretty clear even so; the use of the term "mutant" itself is very nearly unique to the Witcher in medieval-esque fantasy. I certainly pegged it as Witcher-based on my first reading, without any prior knowledge.

Comment: Ah okay I wasn´t sure if that was ment to be a houserule. I thought he got it from somewhere. Thanks for clearing up. I don´t want to change the rules. If it´s not supposed to be, I don´t want it. I thought he maybe used a mechanic already included in DnD and tried to use it for his mutagens. Thats why I was confused.

Comment: I think the last part which basically says 'this rule is pointless in practise' nails it. If your DM wants you to have prep time you will get it, otherwise you won't!